# Passing definition parameter through pdfTeX(pdflatex) does not work

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tex

Commandline for pdflatex:

```
pdflatex main.tex "\def\anonymous{}\include{main}"
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\ifx\anonymous\undefined
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\else
Nam eu velit eget neque mollis imperdiet
\fi
\end{document}
```

The above command line will make PDF file which holds "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".

How can I make the output to hold "Nam eu velit eget neque mollis imperdiet"?

Comment: (in case you would like to produce both versions in one go, have a look at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- `\include{}` is meant to be used to include stuff inside the `document` body. For your case, use `\input{}` instead
- `\def\anonymous{}\input{main}` is to replace `main.tex`, not to be used in addition.

---

```
pdflatex "\def\anonymous{}\input{main}"
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. Also, I noticed if I call `pdflatex main.tex "\def\anonymous{}\input{main}` does not work either.